# FragmentStatePagerAdapter not refreshed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which includes several pagers which are using FragmentStatePagerAdapter as adapters. It works fine the first time when the fragment is created. But when I the fragment is created the second time (for example when I switch tab), the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not updated at all. Here is my code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Activity m_activity;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Activity activity) {
        super(fm);

        m_activity = activity;
        refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.m_fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.m_fragments.size();
    }

    private void refresh() {

        m_fragments = new ArrayList<MyData>();

        // ......
        // after getting data from internet
        notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
}
```

I found the getItem is called the first time. But it's not called the second time although refresh/getCount got called successfully and the data returned from internet is also correct.

What could be reason why the getItem() is not called after the notifyDataSetChanged()? Thanks

**P.S.**: It will be fine when I rotate the device. The getItem() will be called correctly.

**Edit:** The code for the fragment which will use this adapter.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

    // section 1
    m_sectionPager1 = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sectionPager1);

    // section 2
    m_sectionPager2 = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sectionPager2);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // 1
    m_section1Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this.getActivity());
    m_sectionPagerLatest.setAdapter(m_section1Adapter);

    // 2
    m_section2Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this.getActivity());
    m_sectionPagerHottest.setAdapter(m_section2Adapter);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the FragmentStatePagerAdapter refreshed?

Comment: I don't want to say bad words. Can the guy who downvote my question tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
@Override 
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
     return POSITION_NONE; 
}
```

Try this which will recreate the fragment.

Comment: Tried this already. Doesn't work. This method is not called either.

Comment: Ok, then I think if you can add more code, then I can try to see where the problem is?

Comment: I added the code in the Fragment (HomeFragment) which will use this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using `ViewPager2` which does not have the method `getItemPosition`

The solution was to override the method `getItemId` in `FragmentStateAdapter`

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return data[position]?.id ?: 0
}
```